# When trying to request RESTful URI, Jetty log returns "The server sent HTTP status code 503: Service Unavailable"

Tags: rest, jetty, jax-rs

Hey guys I'm trying to create a RESTful webservice that will grab some data from a SAP application through SOAP and then transfer this data to JSON and which will then available be accessed through REST calls.

I'm using Jetty as my application server and when I try to access this URL I get this in my terminal where I'm running Jetty:
`http://localhost:9090/cxf/json/appName/filteredList/someVar=test?nocache=y`
My browser just shows "{"MyData":[]}"

`ERROR - SapSoapHelper              - Loading wsdl from: file:/Users/me/workspace/projects/myProjects/target/classes/wsdl/myWSDL.wsdl
ERROR - SapSoapHelper              - There was a problem calling the web service
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: The server sent HTTP status code 503: Service Unavailable
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.checkStatusCode(HttpTransportPipe.java:196)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:168)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:83)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:105)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:587)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:546)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:531)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:428)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:211)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:124)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:98)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:78)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:107)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy49.runQueryAsAService(Unknown Source)
    at com.cirrus.web.sbus.sapbi.DynOpenOpps.filteredList(DynOpenOpps.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:173)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:89)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:166)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:93)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:106)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:123)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:206)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:213)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:154)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:126)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:184)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doGet(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:112)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:575)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1365)
    at com.cirrus.web.sbus.sapbi.filter.CacheFilter.doFilter(CacheFilter.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1336)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:483)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:520)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:995)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:250)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:351)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:451)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:916)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:647)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:615)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:598)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:533)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)`

I am pretty sure my annotations are correct and I'm wondering if this may be an issue with Jetty. Any advice?

Here's a snippet of my web.xml file, I'm new to REST web services so I'm not sure what other information could be helpful to figure out what's going on.

```
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/cxf/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

FIX: I've finally figured out why this is occurring. I work behind a corporate firewall, and edited my $http_proxy in ~/.bash_profile to accomodate for this. I had to remove my $http_proxy settings from my ~/.bash_profile to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Could be one of the following conditions.

1. Something in your web app is throwing a [javax.servlet.UnavailableException](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/UnavailableException.html) based Exception. Jetty's internal Servlet implementation will catch it and response with a 503 (Service Unavailable).
2. Your webapp is attempting to communicate out to another server that is throwing 503, and this error is just being forwarded back to your client (this assumtion is based on the existence of the `com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe` line in your stack trace)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Yeah my boss mentioned something about the SAP servers we're talking to was under repair this weekend an they still might be down. I just had no idea if this was something wrong with my configuration or theirs because I pulled our project straight from the repo and made no changes.